# C++ new operator with valid vtable without calling constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, malloc, virtual, vtable

Is it possible to create an instance of a class on a heap without calling default constructor and with a valid vtable for inheritance? Let me demonstrate what I will like to do:

```
class A
{
  protected: virtual void _fake_static_method()
  {

  }
};

class B1 : public A
{
  protected: virtual void _fake_static_method()
  {
    std::cout << "Hello";
  }

  public: static void run_fake_static_method()
  {
    B1* dummy = static_cast<B1*>(::operator new(sizeof(B1)));
    dummy->_fake_static_method();
    free(dummy);
  }
}

class B2 : public A
{
  public: static void run_fake_static_method()
  {
    B2* dummy = static_cast<B2*>(::operator new(sizeof(B2)));
    dummy->_fake_static_method();
    free(dummy);
  }
}
```

Here I want to call a static method from example `B1::run_fake_static_method()`. In that method I want to run a member method, but I don't want to call the default constructor. I need such an implementation to remove the virtual method without a compiling error among other errors. Like a "**virtual static method**" I hope you understand what I want to do.

Is there a special trick that I can get this to work? :)

Comment: Yes. Call a different constructor.

Comment: `#define virtual static` - technically UB though.

Comment: You can't mix `operator new` and `free` like that. And can you explain what exactly do you mean with "remove the virtual method without error"?

Comment: Obvious undefined behavior is obvious.

Comment: ...X vs Y problem anyone? (To clarify, what you are doing may be possible, but what are you trying to do with it? There is probably a better pattern out there that will do what you want without being broken as hell)

Comment: In order to call a non-static member function you must have an object. To have an object you must call a constructor. Not necessarily the default one, any constructor will do, but you must call one.

Comment: To add to what @n.m. said, calling any non-static member on an object that hasn't been constructed would be undefined behavior. Undefined behavior can make your life hell in mysterious ways - don't go there.